# Searching for a string on a website to display odds

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display only the odds from bet365 from a javacript piece of code. I can only think of doing this by searching for a part of the id of the bet, each bookie has its own related ids and bet365's is b3, so this query below I've tried to search for ids where the string includes the "b3" in it, as all other parts of it seem completely random

http://www.oddschecker.com/horse-racing/2015-06-30-chepstow/18:10/winner

```
var odds = document.getElementsByTagName("odds");

for (var i = 0; i < odds.length; i++) {

    if(odds[i].id.indexOf("b3") == 0) {

        odds[i].disabled = bDisabled;

    }
}
```

Whenever I do this my return says undefined. How can I get this to work

Comment: What return? How are you retrieving the page in the first place? Is this a browser extension?

Comment: I'd be running it through console on the browser

Comment: Have you tried to print `odds.length`? It would seem weird that they'd have tags called `<odds>` . What elements are you trying to target with `document.getElementsByTagName("odds")`?

Comment: if your are talking about the `undefined` shown in the console, it's because your code does not actually return something (normal behaviour).

Comment: I doubt there are html-elements, with the tag-name: "odds". This is against the standard, even with webcomponents / custom-elements

Comment: I can't find any elements with tag name odds or class .odds on that page. Also, that site loads jQuery so you can always use jQuery to simplify your DOM searching.

Comment: I am very confused. I wanted to be able to search through the tag name id, 

var id = document.getElementsByTagName("id");
for (var i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
  if(id[i].id.indexOf("b3") == 0)
    id[i].disabled = bDisabled;
}

Comment: The id looks like this http://i.gyazo.com/ce285adeb5df737f5c734b87e20702a0.png

Comment: I'm trying to search through the ids to search for ids which include B3 in them

Comment: The terminology seems to be the problem here. `getElementsByTagName()` finds elements by *tag*. The tag in an element `<td id="whatever">` is "td". So you'd use `document.getElementsByTagName("td")`.

Comment: var id = document.getElementsByTagName("td"); 
for (var i = 0; i < id.length; i++) 
{ if(id[i].id.indexOf("b3") == 0) 
id[i].disabled = bDisabled;
}

ends up being undefined too

Comment: What do you expect it to be instead? In any case it seems that "b3" is at the end of the id but you're looking for it at the start (indexOf == 0).

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to using javascript I'm more used to excel and SQL, is there a way in which you can just search for the substring b3?

Comment: Like document.getElementsByTagName("td") where td includes b3 or something like that

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the marker you're looking for is `.co`, from what I can see from the code (delimiting a `td` with the odds as inner content).

The site also has jQuery loaded up, so let's use jQuery to simplify the pseudo-code (we can always transform it to pure javascript later):

```
var odds = $('.co');
odds.each(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if(id.indexOf('_B3') >= 0){
        console.log(id);
        //your code here
    }
});
```

Given that the ID is not at the end of the ID string, we can't check to see if the indexOf is == to 0; instead, we just want to know if the ID we're looking for (b3) is contained in that string. So we're looking for any value that is not -1, the value returned by indexOf when the query is not found in the original string.

I'm searching for specifically for `_B3` for two reasons: One, indexOf is case sensitive, so given that your ID are uppercase, we must make our search uppercase too. I'm also adding the underscore in order to respect the ID string format, as I'm not 100% certain that your ID will only contain letters to delimit IDs from the bet vendor, so we can't be too safe with that.

In pure javascript:

```
var odds = document.getElementsByClassName('co');
for(var ii = 0; ii < odds.length; ii++){
    if(odds[ii].id.indexOf("_B3") >= 0){
        console.log(odds[ii].id);
        //your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: that ends up giving me an error stating Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)

Comment: Sorry about that, I had a typo in the jQuery code block (I'm assuming you've tried that one), throwing a syntax error. try again.

Comment: I tried the pure javascript code version. for the jquery one, if(id.indexOf('_B3')){
        //your code here
    }

How can I get it to only display these results if it includes B£?

Comment: What's B£? Don't you mean B3?

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant to type b3

Comment: The if statement will filter on ids who only contain _B3. You can display the ids in your console by calling console.log(id); (see update on code snippets).

Comment: I still end up with a full list of results both ways unfortunately http://i.gyazo.com/4fd00165022d576caba7e57d3f1dc14b.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81993/discussion-between-prusprus-and-pkgrem).